# Status bar height changes after playing a Youtube video

Tags: video, ios6, statusbar

I have this Web view that loads a list of videos in youtube. After I select and play any of this videos, the Web view is shifted 20 pixels up. I've printed values of status bar before and after playing the video and the height changes from 20 to 0, and this remains across all the app. This only happens with iOS 6, tested in iOS 5 and looks ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, is very similar to this [Modal dismissals do not account for status bar (new iOS 6 issue?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567233/modal-dismissals-do-not-account-for-status-bar-new-ios-6-issue) . I'm using a VC that is not returning the correct supported interface orientations. After changing this, the Web view is always in the right place.