# iOS 7 Status Bar Disappears After Playing a Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm not the only one who's having this kind of issue. Here's another one, [Status bar height changes after playing a Youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483717/status-bar-height-changes-after-playing-a-youtube-video). But I can't still find a way to solve this. I'm not using MPMoviePlayerController. I think I just have to use these codes;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];

self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                20.0,
                                self.webView.frame.size.width,
                                self.webView.frame.size.height);
```

But it's not so working.

Please see this images below..

[image]

At first this is what my "Home" looks like.

[image]

Status bar disappears while playing a video from Youtube/Vimeo (or whatever).

[image]

When I go back, see them bunched up.

[image]

Found out that FB figure out how to handle this. They had their status bar appears right there.

Any help???

Cheers in advance!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if apply for your case, but in my case the status bar appears after I loaded a UIImagePickerController and change my default screen orientation.

I fix this situation add **application.statusBarHidden = YES;** inside appDelegate like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
// Detect if I need to hide the StatusBar (optional)
if (iNeedToHide == YES) {  
    application.statusBarHidden = YES;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
```

}

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to make the status bar appear when playing the video to prevent the other screens to have their navigation bar bunched up with status bar. I made it appear when opening the Youtube/Vimeo site but when I play a vid, it disappears..

Comment: I don't know if your video control is a kind of Navigation Controller, but if it is you can use this delegate procedure and hide the status bar: // Esto se usa para quitar el statusBar dentro de las operaciones del UIImagePicker
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{    // Esconder el StatusBar. Provocado por el iOS7 y el UIImagePickerController
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable the animation when dismissing the video player. Place a notification for video did finish event:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:controller.moviePlayer];
```

Then, inside the method, dismiss the view controller without animation:

```
- (void)videoDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:controller.moviePlayer];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```