# iOS 7: Status Bar remains hidden after exiting fullscreen video and using CJPAdController

Tags: ios, iphone, video, youtube, statusbar

I have an app that has a tabbar controller with navigation controllers on each tab.

In one of the tabs, user can play videos and they can set them in fullscreen. I use LBYoutTubeView to be able to show YouTube videos and use the following code to show it:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

if (controller.playbackState != MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying && controller.playbackState != MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
    controller = [[LBYouTubePlayerController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", video]] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
    CGRect f = self.view.frame;

    if ([self systemMajorVersion] < 7) {
        controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,f.size.width, f.size.height);
    }else{
        controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,f.size.width, f.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);
    }

    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    controller.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitFullScreen:) name:@"MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:controller];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterFullScreen:) name:@"MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification" object:controller];
}
}
```

This was working fine until I implemented [CJPAdController](https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController) library, which is a great tool to handle ads. Basically, I added ads at the bottom, below the tabbar controller and when video exits from fullscreen, the status bar remains hidden and I can't displayed it again. This happens only on iOS 7, on iOS 6 it's working fine.

I tried the following stuff:

```
- (void)exitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification{
[controller pause];
    NSLog(@"%hhd",[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    NSLog(@"%hhd",[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden);
}
```

It always prints "1".

I also added the following to the tabbar controller and navigation controller

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

Also tried with [IOS 6 - Status Bar Not Showing after Playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618981/ios-6-status-bar-not-showing-after-playing-video) , [iOS 7 Status Bar Disappears After Playing a Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291562/ios-7-status-bar-disappears-after-playing-a-video),

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem with iOS 8.1

Comment: I saw your workaround in https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController/issues/14. Thanks!